# How to recreate the UITabBarItem image filter?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbar

I'm writing a custom UITabBar replacement, and I would like to know how to recreate the filter that the built-in implementation does with the UITabBarItem image - that blue shining on selected tabs and gray gradient on unselected ones. I guess it's a matter of using the source image alpha value as a mask and overlay it with a pre-made blue (or whatever color) shining image and another one grayed out, but I would like to know what is the best approach from a code point of view.

Best,

Comment: you could simply use two different images (with grayed out and highlighted content) for each tab and switch between them on click of the tab button... (of course this is valid if you are creating this custom tab bar replacement just for your app and not as a reusable component)

Comment: Hi lukya, thanks for your feedback. Using two images for each item is the obvious solution, but I want to accomplish it codewise to make it reusable, just like you said.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit: Fixed up the blue filter a little
Edit2: Cleaned up the grey filter

I required code to do these effects, so I wrote a couple functions for them:

```
UIImage *grayTabBarItemFilter(UIImage *image) {
    int width = image.size.width, height = image.size.height;
    UIImage *result = image;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if (colorSpace == NULL) {
        return result;
    }
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, width * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    if (context == NULL) {
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        return result;
    }
    CGFloat colors[8] = {80/255.0,80/255.0,80/255.0,1, 175/255.0,175/255.0,175/255.0,1};
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0,-(32-height)/2.0), CGPointMake(0,height+(32-height)/2.0), 0);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationIn);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0,0,width,height), image.CGImage);
    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    if (newImage != NULL) {
        result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];
        CGImageRelease(newImage);
    }
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return result;
}

struct RGBA {
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char alpha;
};

#define BLUE_ALPHA_THRESHOLD 128
#define BLUE_BRIGHTNESS_ADJUST 30

UIImage *blueTabBarItemFilter(UIImage *image) {
    int width = image.size.width,
        height = image.size.height;
    UIImage *result = image;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if (colorSpace == NULL) {
        return result;
    }
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, width * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    if (context == NULL) {
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        return result;
    }
    UIImage *gradient = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selection_gradient.png"];
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-(gradient.size.width - width) / 2.0, -(gradient.size.height - height) / 2.0, gradient.size.width, gradient.size.height), gradient.CGImage);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationIn);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0,0,width,height), image.CGImage);
    struct RGBA *pixels = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);
    if (pixels != NULL) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int offset = x+y*width;
                if (pixels[offset].alpha >= BLUE_ALPHA_THRESHOLD && 
                    ((x == 0 || x == width-1 || y == 0 || y == height-1) ||
                     (pixels[x+(y-1)*width].alpha < BLUE_ALPHA_THRESHOLD) ||
                     (pixels[x+1+y*width].alpha < BLUE_ALPHA_THRESHOLD) ||
                     (pixels[x+(y+1)*width].alpha < BLUE_ALPHA_THRESHOLD) ||
                     (pixels[x-1+y*width].alpha < BLUE_ALPHA_THRESHOLD))) {
                    pixels[offset].red = MIN(pixels[offset].red + BLUE_BRIGHTNESS_ADJUST,255);
                    pixels[offset].green = MIN(pixels[offset].green + BLUE_BRIGHTNESS_ADJUST,255);
                    pixels[offset].blue = MIN(pixels[offset].blue + BLUE_BRIGHTNESS_ADJUST,255);
                }
            }
        }
        CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
        if (image != NULL) {
            result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
            CGImageRelease(image);
        }
    }
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return result;
}
```

To make the blue filter effect work you'll need to include this image in your project as "selection_gradient.png": [image: selection_gradient.png]

Also, you may want to play with the defines to get the effect exactly how you like, I didn't take much time to perfect them, though they look good enough to me.

Of course I don't know the exact filters that Apple applied, but I "guestimated" them and they look alright to me. I'm not sure if these functions are iPhone 4 compatible because I'm only using them in an iPad app, but it wouldn't be hard to edit them to your liking.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this filter to work on retina devices. Has anyone had any success doing that? I've tried CGContextScaleCTM() but that just makes the image twice as big.

Comment: You should just have to change `result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];` to `result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];`

Comment: I actually figured out a way to exactly replicate the UITabBarItem filter. It's a bit of a hack, but it's a pixel-perfect copy. I'll post my solution in a moment.

Comment: Just posted my answer. Gives both blue and grey filters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one; it's shorter:

```
+ (UIImage *)blendImageBlue:(UIImage *)senderImage {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selection_gradient"];

        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(senderImage.size.width, senderImage.size.height);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

        [senderImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeSourceAtop alpha:0.8];

        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;
}
```

Edit: Use @poiuy_qwert's "selection_gradient.png"

Comment: Havn't tested your code, but from what I can tell this doesn't brighten the edges of the icon?

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in an exact replica of the UITabBarItem filter, then try this solution. You don't need to include any extra images into your project.

I'm fully aware that this is a total hack and I make no promises as to compatibility in the future, but it works in both iOS 5 and iOS 6 as far as I can tell, and with proper error handling I think it can be useful. Here it goes:

```
UIImage *grayTabBarItemFilter(UIImage *image) {
    UITabBar* bar = [[UITabBar alloc] init];
    UITabBarItem* item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" image:image tag:0];
    [bar setItems:@[item]];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] addSubview:bar];
    UIImage* returnImage;
    for(UIView* view in bar.subviews) {
        for(UIView* small in view.subviews) {
            if([small respondsToSelector:@selector(image)]) {
                returnImage = [(UIImageView*)small image];
            }
        }
    }

    [bar removeFromSuperview];

    return returnImage ? returnImage : image;
}

UIImage *blueTabBarItemFilter(UIImage *image) {
    UITabBar* bar = [[UITabBar alloc] init];
    UITabBarItem* item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" image:image tag:0];
    [bar setItems:@[item]];
    [bar setSelectedItem:item];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] addSubview:bar];
    UIImage* returnImage;
    for(UIView* view in bar.subviews) {
        NSInteger count = 0;
        for(UIView* small in view.subviews) {
            if([small respondsToSelector:@selector(image)]) {
                count++;
                if(count > 1) {
                    returnImage = [(UIImageView*)small image];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [bar removeFromSuperview];

    return returnImage ? returnImage : image;
}
```

Again, I'm aware that this is a shaky solution at best, but if you're interested in a perfect replica, here it is.